# ModX: Using Ditto with template variables

Tags: templates, modx, modx-evolution, ditto

I am having a great deal of difficulty getting my head round displaying secveral resources on one page with Ditto. I cant seem to get TV's to show along with my content.

Heres how I have set it out:

- I have a page with my Ditto call:

  `[!Ditto? &parents='134' &orderBy='createdon ASC' &tpl='temp'!]`
- I have a simple chunk called `temp` set up as such:

  `<div id="content">
  [*articlename*]
  [+content+]
  </div>`
- And I have a template with the TV `articlename` assigned to all the resource under parent 134.

The content shows fine but none of the TV's do. Can anyone point me in the right direction? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in your syntax. You need to use a placeholder tag in the chunk for your TV:

Try this:

```
<div id="content"> [+articlename+] [+content+] </div>
```

Comment: LOL we posted at the exact same time :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer: You are meant to use `[+articlename+]` for 'chunk TVs' rather then `[*articlename*]`. This is different to getResources.